# Simultaneous solvability of two linear inequality systems

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Consider the two linear systems
$$
A^Ty \geq 0 \\
b^T y \leq -1 \\
y \geq 0
$$
and
$$
A^Tz \geq 0 \\
b^T z < 0
$$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

I have to show that either both systems have a solution or neither.

I tried to use Farkas' Lemma here, but that didn't work out.

Comment: You forgot something. When $m=n=1$, $A=-1$, $b=1$ the second system has a solution $z=-1$ but the first has no solution.

Comment: Not missing a $z \ge 0$?